# How to style the entire react-select as a whole with display property

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have looked at this [style guide](https://react-select.com/styles#style-object) and it really isn't written well at all. I have a whole list of all of the component pieces, but I have no idea how they nest. All I am looking to do is get the whole component to line up inline-block so it will fall on the same line as my label before it. But I cannot get the right part. Any help is appreciated. This component is so hard to style now for simple items. 
Here is my code so far:

```
const customControlStyles = {
    container : (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        width: 100, 
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        display:'inline-block'
    }),
    menu : (provided, state) => ({
        ...provided,
        width: 100, 
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        color: 'black'
    })
```

Comment: I was able to put span tags around it and add style={{display:'inline-block'}}, but I shouldn't have to add extra markup to do this, container should allow me to put inline-block on it.

Comment: Can you update your question with the design you try to achieve ? Also I recommend you to check the source code to see how nested the components are.

Comment: I am not doing any rocket science, I simply wanted to get the whole component to be display: inline-block, but when I do that on container, it places parts of the component on top of each other and it does not move to the same line as other components.

Comment: I'm asking because I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve and on my side when I use your code that's the result https://codesandbox.io/s/1vql79p7ml

Comment: something must be conflicting on my css somewhere. Mine does not look like that. Thanks.